# Creating multiple instances and add as a linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to sql server.

I create a default instance during installation of SQL server 2008. I then add 2 instances to it. Will it be possible to add these instances as linked server to default instance.

Comment: http://blog.daksatech.com/2011/07/create-linked-server-to-itself-in-ms.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes just add them as linked servers in the normal mannor

Info about adding linked servers

http://www.jensbits.com/2010/11/10/create-linked-server-sql-server-2008/

Adding linked server with t-sql

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx

Comment: I created a linked server as mentioned in the link and associated a database to it. However I get "Deferred prepare could not be completed message" . What could be the reason..

Comment: is this when you are running a query if so did you specify a alias?